# Need To Show Directory Output as Full Name Instead of Email Address

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm following the steps in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgYYTD20mTE&feature=player_embedded) to create a Comments Section.

James (the author) created two models, then creates a relation between the two, then creates a table to add/edit comments/notes.

He uses the following Event in one model:

```
onCreate    
record.reported_by = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();    
record.Date = new Date();
```

and the following Event in the second.

```
onCreate
record.Tech = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
record.Date = new Date();
```

Now if you have a label that is bound to the relationship, it will show the email address of the user who created the new item.

All that is working perfectly. I was just trying to figure out a way to have the label display the Full Name instead of the Email Address.

I was hoping it would be something simple like switching getEmail with something like getFullName, but no such luck.

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to change the binding of the widget?

Answer (score 3):

Afaik at this time there is no built-in method in App Maker to get current user Full Name, but you can get it by adding [Directory model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory) to your application. After you added Directory model you have multiple ways to serve user's Full Name:

1 Save it to your database when record is created

```
// onCreate
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

var directoryQuery = app.models.Directory.newQuery();
directoryQuery.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = email;
var reporter = directoryQuery.run()[0];

record.reported_by = email;
record.reported_full_name = reporter.FullName;
record.Date = new Date();
```

and then use this 'reported_full_name' in binding instead of 'reported_by'.

- pros - better performance when you render multiple records on UI
- cons values in your DB can eventually become obsolete

2 Use calculated model and make dynamic 'virtual relation' between your local model and Directory

- pros - you will always have actual data
- cons - it will work slower, it will be harder to maintain and implement

3 Query server for Full Name after datasource is loaded on UI

```
// widget binding
setFullName(widget, @datasource.item.reported_by)

// client script
setFullName(widget, email) {
  google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(fullName) {
           widget.text = fullName;
         })
         .getFullName(email);
}

// server script
function getFullName(email) {
  var directoryQuery = app.models.Directory.newQuery();
  directoryQuery.filters.PrimaryEmail._equals = email;
  var person = directoryQuery.run()[0];

  return person.FullName;
}
```

- pros - you will always have actual data
- cons - labels on UI will blink, worse performance due to big number requests to server

Comment: Maybe you also want your app to look better and more social, then you can  store ThumbnailPhotoUrl in database as well and  bound it to Image widget.